# Model training stage: validation_data with the same data set

Tags: r, keras

I would like someone to explain to me why when I do a training with a `validation_data` identical to the training data set, I get two curves that are different and not superimposed?

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(50 * 10), nrow = 50)
y <- matrix(rnorm(50), nrow = 50)

model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, input_shape = dim(x)[2]) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 1) %>%
  layer_activation("linear")

model %>% compile(
  loss = "mse",
  optimizer = "adam",
  metrics = "mse"
)

history <- model %>% fit(x, y, batch_size = 1, epochs = 10, verbose = 1, validation_data = list(x, y))
plot(history)
```

[image]

Comment: hello, FalconUA answered my questioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some reasons why that might happened:

1. The **`loss`** is calculated and averaged ***during training***. That means between loss calculations there are gradient updates, so the next loss over minibatch is the loss over a ***different*** model. On other hand, **`val_loss`** is calculated ***after training***, over the ***same*** model for the whole dataset. That's why they are different in value.

   To put it visually, it is like this:

   ```
   Epoch 1:
     batch_1 -> nnet_1 -> loss_1 -> optimize nnet_1 to nnet_2
     batch_2 -> nnet_2 -> loss_2 -> optimize nnet_2 to nnet_3
     ...
     batch_n -> nnet_n -> loss_n -> optimize nnet_n-1 to nnet_n
   loss = loss_1 + loss_2 + ... + loss_n
   val_loss = loss of the nnet_n over whole dataset
   ```

   you see how their calculation differs?
2. During training (when **`loss`** is calculated), ***dropout*** is enabled. After training (validation phase, when **`val_loss`** is calculated, ***dropout*** is disabled.